# Server validation In app purchase receipt of OSX app

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, receipt

I am working on In app Purchase validate on OSX app and get some problem~

My request code like this:

```
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]];
    NSString* base64Str = [data base64EncodedString];

    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:base64Str forKey:@"receipt-data"];
    SBJSON *jsonParser = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString* jsonStr = [jsonParser stringWithObject:dict error:nil];
    postUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];

    _verifyRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [_verifyRequest setTimeoutInterval:_sTimeoutInterval];
    [_verifyRequest setURL:postUrl];
    [_verifyRequest setHTTPBody:[jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [_verifyRequest setHTTPMethod:ASCommon_HttpMethodPost];
    _verifyConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_verifyRequest delegate:self];
    [_verifyConnection start];
```

I get the result like this

```
{
    exception = "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException";
    status = 21002;
}
```

And I log the jsonStr variable seems have no problem:

```
{"receipt-data":"..........................................................."}
```

[Apple doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1) said "Retrieve the receipt data. ...... On OS X, this is the entire contents of the receipt file inside the application bundle. Encode the receipt data using base64 encoding."

Do I misunderstand the receipt data is entire of contents of file? Or something wrong with my code?

Comment: @VBK no yet.... I use local receipt validate only....

Answer (score 1):

I think i found a solution. The base64 encoded string class by default  doesnt remove line breaks. You need to change it to remove line breaks. Change this function:

```
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString
{
    size_t outputLength;
    char *outputBuffer =
        NewBase64Encode([self bytes], [self length], true, &outputLength);

    NSString *result =
        [[[NSString alloc]
            initWithBytes:outputBuffer
            length:outputLength
            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
        autorelease];
    free(outputBuffer);
    return result;
}
```

to

```
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString : (BOOL)includeLineBreaks
{
    size_t outputLength;
    char *outputBuffer =
        NewBase64Encode([self bytes], [self length], includeLineBreaks, &outputLength);

    NSString *result =
        [[[NSString alloc]
            initWithBytes:outputBuffer
            length:outputLength
            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
        autorelease];
    free(outputBuffer);
    return result;
}
```

and pass NO in the parameter.